# How to prevent black fringe from appearing after resizing in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a light gray graphic atop a darker gray background. I flattened this file with CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+E. Then I chose the crop tool and specified a smaller crop width. After the crop + automatic resize, the graphic developed a dark fringe. How do I crop/resize without introducing this fringe?

[image: photoshop black fringe]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your 'object' layer and background layer separated.

<sub>( I'm not talking about just *the* background layer, but the layer that creates the background for the 'object' )</sub>

<sub>After resizing is done you can merge it all you want.</sub>

---

If it is in the same layer as the background color, they will have blending party which creates little baby pixels that are tad different than their dull parent...

[image]

---

Because there's couple different things you can do, I decided to add this in this answer.

So possible solutions for avoiding this when resizing your image.

### 1.

Use Image Resize to scale your image. ( Absolutely best way to scale your Layer Styles )

**Image > Image Resize..** ( Ctrl+Alt+I )

This way you dont have to flatter everything to retain the size of your beloved **Layer Styles**

Note the checkboxs with **Scale styles**? It scales Layer styles accordingly. 
[image]

---

### 2.

You can Rasterize the effects to the layers.. You can either right click the **Effects** or the  **FX** icon in the layer panel and choose **Create Layers..** from the list.

And another thing is something I use a lot, but first select every layer except background layer ( this asuming that *background layer* is the only layer that gives bg to the elements. )

You can select all the layers with ( Ctrl+Alt+A ), this will leave *Background layer* unselected ( though if you've made it into a layer then just drop that off by clicking it while pressing Ctrl )

Then group all the layers ( Ctrl+G ) and then merge them all together ( Ctrl+E )

Then you might want to group and merge background layer on its own and resize.

---

### 3.

After resizing with, say **Free transform**, you can use **Scale Layer Effects** by first selecting the layer for which you want to do this and then going to **Layer > Layer Style > Scale Layer Effects** ( Or right clicking the **Effects** or the  **FX** icon in the layer panel and choosing it from the list. )

[image]

Downside, you pretty much in this case have to know the scaling % to be able to scale it to the exact size and this can be done to one layer at a time.

Comment: It is not shown in my sample screenshot, but the background layer actually has a stroke. Anytime there are styles applied to layers, I flatten before resizing for export. Otherwise, the styles do not scale. How would I take this into effect with your method of preventing the black fringe?

Comment: @JoJo I added 3 different solutions for that, the first one is absolutely the sanest thing to do..

Comment: @JoJo: Lollero's advice is dead on. He's showing you how to work WITH the tools rather than against them, which is actually what you're doing with your current workflow.

Comment: Scaling of effects is not as easy as it seems. Say you have a drop shadow of size 2px in your original layout and your exported image needs to be 75% smaller. When the style is scaled by 75%, the 2px drop shadow becomes 1.75px. Photoshop will round that up back to 2px, so in effect, your style didn't get scaled at all. Flattening is the only way to use fractional pixels. Photoshop will interpolate smoothly when scaling a flattened image.

Comment: @JoJo I'm not sure if you meant the feature called "Flatten Image" and if you did, it's not the only way. My second possible solution for that Essentially does the same thing.. You just rasterize layer styles into the layer(s) and it will do the same thing Except you can keep the background color in its own layer.

Comment: When I talk about flattening, I mean merging all layers into one layer. This can be done several ways: **A)** click the highest layer you want flattened, then CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+E. **B)** Select specific layers you want flattened, then CTRL+E. **C)** Layer > Flatten Image. /// Your third option of creating layers from the style is destructive. More than once, have I accidentally "rasterized" or flattened and accidentally saved. My method A is non-destructive, because it creates the flattened image on top of all your original images.

Comment: @JoJo If you have destructice habits.. It's better to be safe than sorry. i just wanted to make sure youre not flattening all of the layers just like you did before when you got this problem, cause flattening layers sounded a lot like flattening them all into one.